# @SuppressWarnings vs @SuppressLint

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Can anyone explain to me the differences between `@SuppressWarnings` and `@SuppressLint`? When we should use one over another?

I've read the documentation, but still don't get the differences. Explain using an example/sample code will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I can't find a difference other than SuppressWarnings being for all of java and SuppressLint being android only

Comment: It's very simple. Warnings are generated by the compiler, as opposed to the lint program.  For example, a deprecated code warning comes from the compiler, so you use `@SuppressWarnings` to quiet it.  A message e.g. API later than your minSdkVersion comes from lint, so you use `@SuppressLint`.

Comment: @krislarson is there a reason why you didn't post that as an answer? That seems to answer the question perfectly

Comment: @BartekLipinski Don't know, maybe I thought the question would get shut down as it doesn't involve actual code. However, with 5 upvotes on the question, a proper answer seems appropriate here, so I'll go ahead and add that. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are actually *two* lints: one belongs to the compiler, so is Java-specific, and one belongs to Google and is Android-specific.

If your warning is about something in Java that isn't specific to Android, it's suppressed with `@SuppressWarnings`, and if it's Android-specific, it's suppressed with `@SuppressLint`.

### Android Lint Warnings

Lint warnings are listed here: http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks

So let's say you have a warning about missing permissions, and the warning description starts off "This check scans through your code and libraries and looks at the APIs being used, and checks this against the set of permissions required to access those APIs."  In the lint warnings page linked above, we find this:

> ### MissingPermission
>
> Summary: Missing Permissions
>
> Priority: 9 / 10
>   Severity: Error
>   Category: Correctness
>
> This check scans through your code and libraries and looks at the APIs being used, and checks this against the set of permissions required to access those APIs. If the code using those APIs is called at runtime, then the program will crash.
>
> Furthermore, for permissions that are revocable (with targetSdkVersion 23), client code must also be prepared to handle the calls throwing an exception if the user rejects the request for permission at runtime.

So to suppress this, we put this annotation on the code:

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
```

### Compiler Warnings

Let's say we find this warning:

"Unchecked cast: 'java.lang.Object' to 'java.lang.Integer' ..."

If you are reading this in hover popup in Android Studio, there is a `More...` link at the end.  When you click the `More...` link, the text expands and you find this at the bottom:

"Hint: Pass -Xlint:unchecked to javac to get more details."

This tells you that you would use "unchecked" in the annotation like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

For a list of compiler warnings, run `javac -X`:

```
C:\>javac -X
  -Xlint                     Enable recommended warnings
  -Xlint:{all,auxiliaryclass,cast,classfile,deprecation,dep-ann,divzero,empty,fallthrough,finally,options,overloads,overrides,path,processing,rawtypes,serial,static,try,unchecked,varargs,-auxiliaryclass,-cast,-classfile,-deprecation,-dep-ann,-divzero,-empty,-fallthrough,-finally,-options,-overloads,-overrides,-path,-processing,-rawtypes,-serial,-static,-try,-unchecked,-varargs,none} Enable or disable specific warnings
  .
  .
  .
```

Those are the values that you can use in `@SuppressWarnings`.

Comment: Thanks for this very helpful explanation. For those like me who are still unsure of what is Android-specific and what isn't: It turns out that using deprecated Android classes and methods is *not* Android-specific. Use `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` to suppress.

Comment: @LarsH Yes, that's because Google uses a common Java annotation to mark classes/methods as deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Also, there is `@Suppress` (kotlin.Suppress) which suppresses Android warnings as well as `@SuppressLint`.

For example, `@Suppress("AlwaysShowAction")`.